# NodeJS app failed with "Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch"

Tags: node.js, heroku, purescript

I am getting error saying `Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch` when I try to start the app, I am pretty sure I've configured the app to use the $PORT env variable provided by Heroku, as I could see the line saying `Server running on 38594` in the log, the port will change every time I restarted the dyno, I tried to login bash with `heroku run bash` and start the app from within there with `node dist/bundle/index.js`, and it works without any error, but I could still not open the app from browser, could someone help to point me to the right direction? cheers

Comment: I also followed the points listed in https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error, no luck

Comment: Share the code where you are binding to the port + name of file. As well as your `package.json`

Comment: @TinNguyen here's the gist https://gist.github.com/leomayleomay/8792539be117965550d50bac5d209882

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out HTTPure was trying to bind to `localhost`, while Heroku allows `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`. The most confusing part is the master branch of HTTPure is binding to `0.0.0.0` https://github.com/cprussin/purescript-httpure/blob/master/src/HTTPure/Server.purs#L84 while the released version I am using is binding to `localhost`, the fix is to use `serve'` with `0.0.0.0` to bind to the correct hostname